# Functional completeness for a ternary operator

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

If I define a ternary logical connective $\clubsuit(a,b,c)$ by the following truth table:
\begin{array}{ccc|c}a&b&c&\clubsuit(a,b,c)\\\hline T&T&T&F\\T&T&F&F\\T&F&T&F\\T&F&F&T\\F&T&T&F\\F&T&F&T\\F&F&T&T\\F&F&F&T\end{array}
(whatever it means, $\clubsuit(a,b,c)$ is true when at most one of $\left\{a,b,c\right\}$ is true), how do I determine whether or not the set $\left\{\clubsuit\right\}$ is functionally complete?

Comment: It is symmetric, hence cannot be complete.

Comment: @user58697 Care to elaborate?

Comment: You can follow user58697's suggestion about symmetry: you cannot discriminate in $p \to q$ the two cases $T-F$ and $F-T$.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I said *symmetric*, it is a translation error. In English this property is known as *self-dual*: function is self dual if $f(x) = \neg{f(\neg{x})}$, which is the case for your function. A complete set must contain a non-self-dual function.

The self-duality is inherited under composition: any composition of self-dual functions is self-dual as well. Therefore it is not possible to express a *not* self-dual function.

Comment: Why must a complete set contain a non-self-dual function though?

Comment: That is Post's theorem; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness#Characterization_of_functional_completeness

Comment: Yes, but again, why? Where/how does my $\clubsuit(a,b,c)$ fail to be complete? From the Wikipedia page you linked "_In logic, a functionally complete set of logical connectives or Boolean operators is one which can be used to express all possible truth tables by combining members of the set into a Boolean expression_". This is the definition that makes the most sense to me, but I'm having trouble seeing how $\clubsuit$ fails to satisfy it. Also, as a side note, would my operator by any chance actually be the [ternary majority function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_function)?

Comment: @Demosthene - it seems to me that it is the negation of the ternary majority function ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, indeed, you're right. Is it a minority function then? :)

Comment: Yes, it is; Enderton call it so: see page 52.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that this question has not been answered fully yet and since I have to prove that $\clubsuit$ is not functionally complete, I'd like to give it a go. My approach would be the following:

1. Prove that the minority function is self-dual. This should be easy to do, just say that if $\clubsuit$(a,b,c) is true, that means that the majority of a, b and c are false. Flipping their values would make them true, thus making $\clubsuit$(a,b,c) false. Same goes for $\clubsuit$(a,b,c) being false.
2. Suppose you have a language with a single variable, $A$, and the minority function. Then, you can argue that there is no way to get a function that always produces the same logical valuation (let's say true) for $A$ being either True and False. Indeed, since we have proven in 1. that flipping the value of what is inside the $\clubsuit$ operator always changes its value, flipping the value of $A$ will always result in a different logical valuation.

The above "hides" another proof: $\{\clubsuit, \mathcal{F}\}$ is indeed complete.

I am new to logic and would appreciate if someone could point out any mistakes.